# Query to retrieve the data for login and logout from two different tables group by user

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, sql-order-by

I am trying to build a query to retrieve data from two different tables

```
Punch(
    punchId int, 
    UserId int, 
    Punch_In_Time datetime , 
    Punch_Out_time datetime
)

Users(
    UserID int, 
    User_Name varchar
);
```

Wanted to build a query that can fetch data from these two tables group by UserName, order By PunchInTime.

I tried doing it but it only returns the first login and last logout of a person. As I want all login and logouts performed by a user.

Query tried : SELECT  users.full_name,

```
   punch.punch_in  AS login
  ,punch.punch_out AS logout
```

FROM   users join punch where users.id = punch.user_id
GROUP  BY full_name, date(punch_in)
ORDER  BY full_name, date(punch_in);

only one row per username is showing.

Solutions are welcomed

Comment: what code have you used so far?

Comment: Always show us the code you have so far, often it gives us more insight to your problem than the description you provide

Comment: It might be worth looking up what GROUP BY does in one of the miriad of SQL tutorials out there on the web, it sounds like that is causing your problem of only seeing one row per user

Comment: exactly @RiggsFolly Only one row is coming at one time. I want all user's data grouped by username only.

Comment: As I was trying to intimate, if you `group by SomeColumn` then you will only ever see ONE of those columns in the result

Comment: @RiggsFolly can u suggest the right way? or if can explain more.

Comment: _"... FROM users join punch where users.id = punch.user_id ..."_ I think the `where` here should rather be an `On`